# Is it valid to add an entire array of bytes at once by converting them to a larger integer data type?

Tags: math, optimization, rust

If I have two arrays that contain `u8`s, can I convert them into a larger integer type to reduce the number of additions I need to do? For example, if two byte arrays each contain 4 bytes, can I make them each into a `u32`, do the addition, and then convert them back?

For example:

```rust
let a = u32::from_ne_bytes([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let b = u32::from_ne_bytes([5, 6, 7, 8]);

let c = a + b;
let c_bytes = u32::to_ne_bytes(c);

assert_eq!(c_bytes, [6, 8, 10, 12]);
```

This example results in the correct output.

1. Does this always result in the right output (assuming there is no overflow)?
2. Is this faster than just doing the additions individually?
3. Does it hold true for other integer types? Such as 2 `u16`s in a `u32` added with 2 other `u16`s in a `u32`?

If this exists and is common, what is it called?

Comment: *assuming there is no overflow* — why is this assumption valid? Does it not matter if you get the correct result sometimes?

Comment: Typically these optimizations are not necessary and may not even be faster due to cache lines and such. Only do them when you have ruled out other known performance issues. Edit: Also I don't think your logic checks out, this will fail in certain cases due to overflow.

Comment: @Shepmaster I am wanting to know from a theoretical perspective... If what I am describing is a "thing", is there some way to handle the overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does this always result in the right output (assuming there is no overflow)?

Yes. Provided that each sum is less than 256, this will add the bytes as you want. You've specified "ne" in each case, for native endianness. This will work, regardless of the native endianness because the operations are byte-wise.

If you wrote code to actually check that the sums are all in range, then you would almost certainly undo any extra speed-up that you had got (if there was any to begin with).

> 2. Is this faster than just doing the additions individually?

Maybe. The only way to know for sure is to test.

> 3. Does it hold true for other integer types? Such as 2 `u16`s in a `u32` added with 2 other `u16`s in a `u32`?

Yes, but you need to pay attention to byte order.

> If this exists and is common, what is it called?

It's not common because it's usually unnecessary. This type of optimisation makes code harder to read and introduces considerable complexity and opportunities for bugs. The Rust compiler and LLVM between them are able to find extremely sophisticated optimisations, that you would never think of, while your code stays readable and maintainable.

If it has a name, it's SIMD, and most modern processor support a form of it natively (SSE, MMX, AVX). You can do this manually, using the built-in functions, e.g. [`core::arch::x86_64::_mm_add_epi8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.1/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_add_epi8.html), but LLVM might do it automatically. It's possible that trying to do this manually could interfere with optimisations that LLVM would otherwise do, while making your code more bug-prone at the same time.

---

I'm not an expert at assembly code by any means, but I took at a look at the [assembly generated](https://godbolt.org/z/BDsy0X) for the following two functions:

```
#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
pub fn f1(a1: u8, b1: u8, c1: u8, d1: u8, a2: u8, b2: u8, c2: u8, d2: u8) -> [u8; 4]{
    let a = u32::from_le_bytes([a1, b1, c1, d1]);
    let b = u32::from_le_bytes([a2, b2, c2, d2]);
    u32::to_le_bytes(a + b)
}

#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
pub fn f2(a1: u8, b1: u8, c1: u8, d1: u8, a2: u8, b2: u8, c2: u8, d2: u8) -> [u8; 4]{
    [a1 + a2, b1 + b2, c1 + c2, d1 + d2]
}
```

The assembly for `f1`:

```
movzx r10d, byte ptr [rsp + 8]
shl ecx, 24
movzx eax, dl
shl eax, 16
movzx edx, sil
shl edx, 8
movzx esi, dil
or esi, edx
or esi, eax
or esi, ecx
mov ecx, dword ptr [rsp + 16]
shl ecx, 24
shl r10d, 16
movzx edx, r9b
shl edx, 8
movzx eax, r8b
or eax, edx
or eax, r10d
or eax, ecx
add eax, esi
ret
```

And for `f2`:

```
add r8b, dil
add r9b, sil
add dl, byte ptr [rsp + 8]
add cl, byte ptr [rsp + 16]
movzx ecx, cl
shl ecx, 24
movzx edx, dl
shl edx, 16
movzx esi, r9b
shl esi, 8
movzx eax, r8b
or eax, esi
or eax, edx
or eax, ecx
ret
```

Fewer instructions doesn't necessarily make it faster, but it's not a bad guideline.

---

Consider this kind of optimisation as a last resort, after careful measurement and testing.

Comment: The OP said they had arrays, so already contiguous bytes in memory.  Function args means each one is at the bottom of a qword (8 bytes) register or stack slot, so taking advantage of SIMD isn't worth it, and packing them into a struct of u8 results requires all this zero-extending and shifting.  Compilers should use `movd xmm0, [mem]` / `movd xmm1, [mem]` / `paddb xmm0, xmm1` if you write a loop over two 4-byte arrays doing `+` or `wrapping_add`.

Comment: Or I guess with `+` in Rust, that promises no overflow for each sum, so `mov eax, [mem]` / `add eax, [mem]` if you really only have 4 or 8 bytes at once.  (This is called SWAR, SIMD-within-a-register.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR).  `paddb` blocks carry propagation between bytes to give you `wrapping_add` in each element.